# Order by PHP particular echo

Tags: php, sql

Ok i have this in my database as example

```
id |  x | y  | z  | status | statusb
 1 | 20 | 12 | 13 |    1   |    2
 2 | 40 | 32 | -- |    3   |    2
 3 | 50 | 31 | 15 |    2   |    1
```

im doing a select like

```
"select * FROM table ORDER BY GREATEST(COALESCE(x, 0),COALESCE(y, 0), COALESCE(z, 0)) DESC"
```

And the echo inside a for each.. is like

```
if (status==1) { echo $row_x style1}
if (status==2) { echo $row_x style2}
if (status==3) { echo $row_x style3}
if (statusb==1) { echo $row_y style4}
if (statusb==2) { echo $row_y style5}
```

I get something like

```
 id3 - x50 style2
 id3 - y31 style4
 id2 - x40 style3
 id2 - y32 style5
 id1 - x20 style1
 id1 - y12 style5
```

What i need is

```
 id3 - x50 style2
 id2 - x40 style3
 id2 - y32 style5
 id3 - y31 style4
 id1 - x20 style1
 id1 - y12 style5
```

Thanks to Chinnu R for the fast answer the problem is that y or x can have 0 (not null) as default when the col is created the value is 0 unless the user update that..

So my problem is 0 affecting the query using the answer

```
ORDER BY x DESC, y DESC, z desc

id |  x | y  | z  | status | statusb
 1 | 20 | 12 | 13 |    1   |    2
 2 | 40 | 0  | -- |    3   |    2
 3 | 50 | 31 | 15 |    2   |    1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this in SQL query,

```
ORDER BY x DESC, y DESC, z DESC
```

For not null `WHERE y IS NOT NULL`

For not equal to zero, `WHERE y !='0'`

Comment: Works great, the problem i see know if is there is for example a value set for y, for default that column isert a 0 if not value is added.. so this is used as a value.. i cant use null.... how can i make 0 wont affect the other value.. just 0.. I just update the question

Comment: Can you try like, `WHERE y IS NOT NULL`

Comment: But it is always "not null" instead by default (instead of null) i insert a 0.. for other system matters.. but its a 0. or maybe you mean 0 is taken as null?

Comment: you are very kind. this works... but i do not want to "discard" y when 0 i still need to echo x ... if i set WHERE y !='0' i cant get the x value

Comment: `if (statusb==1 && $row_y>0) { echo $row_y style4}`